# VB6: Combo box style 2. Text Property behaviour

Tags: vb6

One of our VB6 project form is having a combo box. It's style is set to 2(Drop-down List Box).

When style is set to 2, its Text property becomes read-only. We cannot assign value to it.

But in our project some one has written code to assign string to Text property, and is working fine.

```
combobox1.Text = "Something" 'working
```

If i create a same kind of combo box with same properties, i am not able to assign string to text property.
I am getting error *runtime error 383 'text' property is read-only*

```
combobox2.Text = "Something" 'Not working
```

Can anyone help me understanding what i am missing.

Comment: Because when someone's code is run "Something" is in the combobox's lit of items. The code slects the existing item. When your code is run "Something" is not in the list and that is the source of your error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why someone else code worked is because they had the dropdown combo property selected and not the dropdown list. You need to add items to the combo list and then set the listindex to 0 as per below -

```
Combo1.AddItem "MyComboCaptionHere"
Combo1.AddItem "Hi"
Combo1.AddItem "There"
Combo1.ListIndex = 0
```

This will show a "caption" of MyComboCaptionHere.